# Could not upload file with PrettyFaces filter

Tags: jsf, gradle, ear, wildfly-8, prettyfaces

When I am adding the filter codes in my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

I am unable to upload a file and getting exception :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: 0
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
........
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.servlet.PrettyFacesWrappedRequest.getParameter(PrettyFacesWrappedRequest.java:55) [prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.containsKey(RequestParameterMap.java:147) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
......
```

The JSF code :

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">
    <h:inputFile id="file"
                 label="file"
                 value="#{myBean.uploadedFile}"
                 required="true"
                 requiredMessage="File not selected !!">
    </h:inputFile>
    <h:message style="color: red" for="file" /><br />

    <h:commandButton id="submit"
                     action="#{myBean.process}"
                     value="upload file">

        <f:param name="product" value="#{param.product}"></f:param>
    </h:commandButton>
    <br />
</h:form>
```

If I remove the filter code from web.xml, I am able to upload file and submit the form , otherwise I am getting the above mentioned exception.

I am using :

- prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3.jar
- rewrite-servlet-2.0.12.Final.jar
- JSF 2.2

**UPDATE :**

After so much research I found the problem.

My project structure is like this  :

```
 parentProject
 |
 |---childProject
```

Where   parentProject is an EAR project and childProject is a web project.

When I add JARs,

- rewrite-servlet-2.0.12.Final.jar
- rewrite-config-prettyfaces-2.0.12.Final.jar

to `childProject/Web-INf/lib`, it works fine.

But the requirement is to add jars to `parentProject/EarContent/lib` , when I am adding jars to this location prettyfaces mapping is not working .

I could not find any solution.

Comment: I am using : prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3.jar + rewrite-servlet-2.0.12.Final.jar  + jsf2.2

Comment: Should I use : rewrite-config-servlet-2.0.12.Final.jar and rewrite-impl-servlet-2.0.12.Final.jar ?

Comment: Yes, you should only use the rewrite 2.0.12.Final artifacts, including rewrite-config-prettyfaces-2.0.12.Final as documented on the prettyfaces website: http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing PrettyFaces and Rewrite in incompatible version. You should use the following dependencies:

```
rewrite-servlet-2.0.12.Final.jar
rewrite-config-prettyfaces-2.0.12.Final.jar
rewrite-integration-faces-2.0.12.Final.jar
```

That should work fine. :)

Comment: And what about entry in web.xml for filter ?

Comment: You don't need to add anything if you are using a Servlet 3.x compatible container. See: http://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/docs/configuration/install

Comment: When Im using rewrite-servlet-2.0.12.Final.jar
rewrite-config-prettyfaces-2.0.12.Final.jar
rewrite-integration-faces-2.0.12.Final.jar ,

I could not even map any URL, for all the url I am getting 404.

I htink the pretty-config.xml is not picking up